# Command line prompt changed in local network

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

I was sitting in my university and working with terminal (mac os, bash). So far i connected to the local wi-fi and after certain amount of time i found out that my cli prompt line changed from default to `h55`
I printed:`echo "$PS1"`
it showed, what it should: `\h:\W \u\$`
Also, my friend told me, that it happen to him too.
I googled that connecting to local network can cause this behaviour
So i wonder, how it works, that connecting to local network can change my prompt line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\h` means your current hostname.  When you connect to a network via dhcp, it will often try to set your hostname for you, and I'm guessing that's what happened here.  You could run `hostname` to confirm what your current hostname is.

Also, I'm assuming that only that hostname part of the prompt changed to `h55`, not the entire thing.  If that is wrong, please update your question with "before" and "after" examples of your prompt.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac

I prefer to shorten this to a simple dollar sign ($) in order to free up space.
To change your default command line prompt, follow these instructions:

1. Navigate to your home directory: `cd ~`
2. Create a file called .bash_profile: `vi .bash_profile`
3. Add the following line (press i) `export PS1="$ "`